# Proving order in real number set

Tags: axioms, real-numbers

Can we prove such a statement, or is it axiomatic ?

$$
\forall (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 ∶(x \leq y)∧(y \leq z)⇒(x \leq z)
$$

Comment: Usually, it comes with the [construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers) of $\Bbb R$ (be it by Dedekind cuts, Cauchy sequences...). $\Bbb R$ is a complete, ordered, commutative field with $\Bbb Q$ as a subfield.

Comment: Depends on the definition of $\le$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relation $\leq$ on the set of real numbers is the paradigmatic relation defining a [partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_order#Formal_definition), because it is *reflexive*, *antisymmetric*, and *transitive*. (Indeed, the relation $\leq$ on $\mathbb R$ is a total order.)

The property you post asserts that $\leq$ is ***transitive*** on $\mathbb R$.

See also: [Real numbers, axiomatic approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Properties).

Comment: You mean transitivity is a property of a construction, and thus there is no point in "proving" it or not ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Pretty much.

Comment: @Gloserio: No -- if we view it as a property of a particular _construction_ of the real numbers, then it can and should be proved. (How the proof goes depends critically of which construction you use). What amWhy is saying, I think, is that it is a property of something we think we understand well enough _without any construction_, and _therefore_ there's no point in proving it.

Comment: Yes, @Henning Thanks for clarifying my thoughts. (You're a great mind-reader!)

Comment: Yes I get that, I think what it means you say (or at least what I get from it) is that we look to prove that the property is verified for a set, not prove the property itself ; meaning : we look into a construction and verify if the property applies.

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another UV =1

Answer (score 1):

That depends on which definitions and axioms you're working from.

In the most common way to develop real analysis, we work in a setting where the basic properties of real numbers are not *proved*, but just *assumed*. Among the things we *assume* is that there is an ordering on the reals that satisfies certain laws such as the one you quote. During this development of real analysis, these assumptions are *axioms*.

Later one may get to prove, using set theory, that there actually exists a set with operations that satisfy the axioms. Afterwards we say that the set we've constructed "is" the real numbers. As part of this existence proof, we of course need to prove from more basic principles that the particular relation on our set we claim works as the ordering satsifies the transitive law.

What the particular connection between the two paragraphs above is, is to a certain extent a matter of temperament and philosophy. It is common to say that what counts as "axioms" in elementary real analysis are effectively just *promises* that "we will prove this later, don't worry about it now". On the other hand, it may arguably be a better description of how (many) mathematicians actually think to say that the real numbers *exist in and of themselves*, and that the axioms of real analysis really *are* axioms; we accept them because they are "obvious". In this view, the point of constructing the real numbers using set theory is not to tell us anything about *them*, but just to construct a set-theoretic *model* of the real numbers, and thereby show that set theory can work as a basis for ordinary mathematical reasoning.